# Unknown Error with Cypher Request for sum() over Subtrees

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to make following cypher request `match (n:FOLDER)-[r*]->(m:FILE) with n,sum(m.size) as calc SET n.calculatedSize=calc` 
after about one minute the cypher browser says `Unknown error`.

My Request should sumarize the size of the whole subtree. So every folder should have a summarized size of all it subitems (FOLDER and FILE). in Production environment there will be about 9million items with a depth of max 15.

Why the Request returns `Unknown error`, is there any better way to achieve the calculated size?

Comment: Are you attempting to run the query from the browser interface or from neo4j-shell? I believe the browser has a one minute timeout.

Comment: @stephenmuss is right about the timeout error. The query is likely still running. Try it in the shell instead of with the browser if you can. Notice too that you are doing a massively redundant calculation. You keep recounting all the files below at each level of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

fadanner,

You might find it is faster to first do a one-level calculation to sum the file sizes into their immediate parent folders, then work up.

```
MATCH (n:FOLDER)-[r]-(m:FILE)
WITH n, sum(m.size) as calc
SET n.calculatedSize = calc
```

Set a temporary property on all FOLDER nodes to indicate whether they have been visited yet.

```
MATCH (m:FOLDER) set m.seen = 0
```

Mark the leaf folders as seen.

```
MATCH (m:FOLDER)
WHERE NOT (m)-[:CONTAINS]->(:FOLDER)
SET m.seen = 1
```

Repeatedly apply this query until the return value is zero to calculate all the sizes.

```
MATCH (m:FOLDER {seen : 0})-[:CONTAINS]->(n:FOLDER)
WITH m, sum(n.seen) AS val1, count(n) AS val2, sum(n.calculatedSize) AS val3
WHERE val1 = val2
SET m.calculatedSize = m.calculatedSize + val3, m.seen=1
RETURN count(m)
```

Once you are done, remove the 'seen' properties with

```
MATCH(m:FOLDER)
REMOVE m.seen
```

Hope this helps.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Thanks, this looks very good. Have only one problem: On Top Folders there are negative values, so I think there is a overflow. Don't know if it is a problem with saving to the graph with neo4jclient in c# or it is a cypher problem in your solution. Any suggestions how to do calculations with  `long` values?

Comment: Good question! I'm not sure of the answer. After doing a small search and a bit of research in Cypher on the question, it appears that if you create properties with large numeric values directly in Cypher, it uses 64-bit floats (which shouldn't suffer from sign errors, but will suffer from roundoff error for values above ~10^15). So this may be an issue in your c# neo4jclient code. The neo4j manual states that properties can be of pretty much any numeric type, so there should be a way to overcome this. I'm not a c# or neo4jclient guy, so I can't help you there.

Comment: After some experimenting I'm a little confused about the arithmetic overflow. If I make a simple `sum(file.size)` there is an overflow. But if I take `file.size` and add for example `100000000000000` there isn't an overflow, even if this number is bigger as `sum(file.size)` should be. So is there a way to type cast the numbers before calculating it with cypher. I doesn`t have any idea to make it calculate without the overflows. Please help me to find the Problem.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? I am using 2.1.3.

Comment: Try this: FOREACH(i in range(1,1000000)|CREATE (:Foo {val : 1000000000})) followed by MATCH (n:Foo) RETURN sum(n.val)

Comment: I'm on 2.1.3,too. Tested your query and as expected the sum was right and there was no overflow. Tested with my original Database I recognized that the overflow is at **2147483647** so I think the values are stored in 32bit int. I also recognized, if I make a simple `sum(TOINT(file.size))` the result is the expected number, a `sum(TOFLOAT(file.size))` gives the same **right** result. So as a workaround I will try with `TOINT()`. But is this the excepted behaviour of `sum()` ?

Comment: I wish I could tell you. Was the size data originally loaded into the database in an older version of Neo4j? The behavior is troubling, isn't it?

Comment: Loaded it to database via neo4jclient, which in fact only sends cypher http requests to the database. Created the nodes with same database Version. 2.1.3. My workaround works but yes it's troubling. May i ask the neo4jclient guys for an idea. But thanks for your Help.

Comment: Do you think there is a faster way to do such calculations, have a setup with 3 mio files structured in 300 000 folders, and the calculation take over  15 min.  Or is it a fault or bad configuration of my server, windows 7 2 core 8gb ram. Even a a simple `match(n:FILE) return count(:FILE)` takes about 6 seconds. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a limit in your variable path length:

```
match (n:FOLDER)-[r*..15]->(m:FILE) 
with n,sum(m.size) as calc 
SET n.calculatedSize=calc
```